# Distribution of iid variates with fixed sum

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, multivariate-distribution

I have $n$ bins, and a pool containing $N$ balls, $N > n$. I do a consecutive $N$ times: I take one of the balls from the pool and put it into a bin randomly selected with uniform probability $1/n$. The iterations are independent from each other, i.e. it's a memoryless process. When I'm done, what's the marginal distribution of the number of balls in each bin, and what is the standard deviation of the sequence of the $n$ numbers of balls in each bin? Is there a statistical test that would allow me to test whether or not the selection process was truly uniform and memoryless?

Comment: This is a Binomial sample, because each bin behaves the same, so it suffices to examine the count in a single specified bin.  From the resulting counts you can't say anything about "memory" in the process, but you can test for uniformity: that's what the standard chi-squared test does.  You can read all about these two problems and their solutions by searching our site.

Comment: Thanks whuber. I ran a number of simulations and could confirm your statement within the simulation's accuracy. Admittedly, I am a little surprised. I am a little surprise because I would have expected the boundary condition that the sum of all bin contents having to be equal to N to distort the marginal distributions, albeit only to some minor degree. However, again within the simulation's accuracy, I could not detect such distortion. So, at least for all practical purposes, it's probably ok to proceed with the Binomial distribution. Thanks for the chi-square suggestion.

Comment: The Binomial distribution is not an approximation.  A good approximation to the multivariate distribution for large $N$ is *iid* Poisson.

Comment: What I'm still struggling to understand is where the boundary condition comes in. The joint distribution of the $n$ variables cannot simply be the $n$-fold convolution of Binomial($N, 1/n$), because that would ignore the fact that the sum of the values must be equal $N$. Hence the "$n$-th root" of the true joint distribution cannot be the Binomial function either, which is why I thought the Binomial was an approximation, albeit for all practical purposes an excellent one.

Comment: Take a look at the definition of a Binomial variable.